# how to test android push nofication in web without server code

Tags: android, push-notification

> i have integrated push notification its working fine. now my server has problem but i wants to show the demo .
>
> Is there any link in web to test the push notification??
>
> i have seen one link in that we can give API key and reg id and whatever message we want we can give send. but i forget that link.
>
> can any one share the link to test the push notification

Comment: You can test from anywhere, including a private network if you use 0.0.0.0/0 as the IP in the API console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this link, all you need to put your required parameters & message

http://gcm-alert.appspot.com/

Answer (score -1):

Try a rest c!ient from a web browser. E.g. Advanced Rest Client extension for chrome.